# What does this sentence splice mean in the 3.4 indexing documentation?

Tags: r, indexing, subset

This sentence splice in [R Language Definition 3.4 Indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing) is unclear:

> For vectors and matrices the [[ forms are rarely used, although they have some slight semantic differences from the [ form (e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute, **and that partial matching is used for character indices**).

Which of the following text is intended?

1. (e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute, as well as [dropping] the partial matching that is used for character indices)
2. (e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute, and is the notation used for partially matching character indices.)
3. (e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute. By the way, partial matching with names or the dimnames attribute is used for character indices.)
4. (e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute. By the way, the partial matching that results from dropping names or the dimnames attribute is used for character indices.)

The comma splice as presented has missing connecting logic suggesting any of these statements. Which is correct, and how do we request the document to be revised? If the meaning is clear and I am misunderstanding something, can we revise it simply due to the English grammar problem? (run-on sentence or sentence splice)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is outdated (maybe the default in `[[` used to be `exact = FALSE`). Nowadays it should say that `[[` can do partial matching whereas `[` cannot (and never could).

```
x <- setNames(1:3, c(1, 2, 31))

x["3"]
#<NA> 
#  NA

x[["3"]]
#Error in x[["3"]] : subscript out of bounds

x["3", exact = FALSE]
#Error in x["3", exact = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions

x[["3", exact = FALSE]]
#[1] 3
```

You could report this to the [R-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel).

Comment: So you are saying that meaning #2 is correct, that the sentence should be edited to read, "(e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute, and is the notation used for partially matching character indices.)" Right?